# Kubernetes can't see my namespace in cmd line but it exist in my dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I run this command :

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

and I don't get any namespace... but when I go in the dashboard I can see 2 namespaces created ?

config :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://name_of_company
  name: cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster
    user: ME
  name: ME@cluster
current-context: ME@cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: MY NAME
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        client-id: MY ID 
        id-token: MY ID TOKEN
        idp-issuer-url: https://name_of_company/multiauth
      name: oidc
```

Comment: `kubectl get ns` gives the namespace , `kubectl config get-contexts` give the contexts in your kubeconfig or the clusters you have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl get ns` gives the namespace (check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) ), kubectl config get-contexts give the contexts in your kubeconfig which describe clusters, users, and contexts. Read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the command `kubectl get namespace` to list namespaces in a cluster.

Please check
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/